# Why is the container div smaller that its content?

Tags: html, css

In the following example, the `<div>` is smaller then its content.
Why? And how do I fix it?

```css
.switcher {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}

.switcher a {
  padding: 30px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class=switcher>
  <a href=#>first</a>
  <a href=#>second</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the specs:

> [**9.4.2 Inline formatting contexts**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting) - In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block. **Horizontal** margins, borders, and padding are respected between these boxes. The boxes may be aligned vertically in different ways: their bottoms or tops may be aligned, or the baselines of text within them may be aligned.

Although `padding` can be applied to all sides of an inline element, but only left and right padding will have an effect on the surrounding content.

The `<a>` tag is an inline element by default. You can set it to inline-block, so that both horizontal and vertical `padding` will be respected. As an inline-block element is placed as an inline element (on the same line as adjacent content), but it behaves as a block element.

```css
.switcher {
  border: 1px dashed green;
}

.switcher a {
  padding: 30px;
  background: orange;
  display: inline-block; /*new*/
}
```

```html
<div class=switcher>
  <a href=#>first</a>
  <a href=#>second</a>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the fix and where is the `why ?` i guess it's more important :)

Comment: yes it's better but am not the downvoter by the way :)

Answer (score -1):

You can contain the the `a` elements by placing a `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` to the `switcher` class

Answer (score -1):

You can make `<a>` tags display block ... as anchor tags are not by default similar as `<div> p h1 h2` 
`<a>` tag and span tag are inline tags. these elements remain inline until you apply some property to display as block. 
so both `display: inline-block` and `display: block` will work.